# @ mentioning chatter request SFDC using simple_salesforce in python

Tags: python, pandas, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to use simple_salesforce to insert a chatter post with an @ mention in salesforce. I've been using simple_salesforce for a while now, it's very easy to use, but this one has me stuck.

I initialize my instance, and create a record I want to insert into my SFDC instance..

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(email, password, security_token)

record = pd.DataFrame({'ParentId':['006a000000rc5GmAAI'],
                       'Body':['this is a test'],
                       'Type':['TextPost']
                       })

record = record.to_dict(orient="records")

results = sf.bulk.feeditem.insert(record)
```

This all works fine.

What I want to do is to @ mention someone in the body of this. I've researched the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009A0GIAU) on salesforce dev. which shows to create json inputs as a list within the body element.

So I've done that here

```
record = pd.DataFrame({'ParentId':['006a000000wb5GmAAI'],
                       'Body':[[{"type":"Text", "text":"Hello..."},
                                 {"type":"Mention","id":"0051300000BmGFkAAN"}]],
                       'Type':['TextPost']
                       })
```

But this kicks back an error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I'm worried this might require a different API than the standard REST API that simple-salesforce uses. Page 93 of the [Chatter REST API Developer Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_chatter_rest_api.pdf) covers this subject. I tried several of the proposed code samples but couldn't get any of them to work. Maybe you'll have more luck!