# simple_salesforce Feed Item @mention problem

Tags: python, pandas, salesforce, apex, simple-salesforce

I have been trying to mention someone using simple salesforce and chatter for past couple of days without success. I have tried different approaches and all of them fail to give me satisfying results.

This works just fine and I am able to create a FeedItem for a specific parentid but @mention renders as a text.

```
record = pd.DataFrame({'ParentId':['parent_salesforce_id']
                      ,'Body':['{%salesforce_id} Test.']
                      ,'Type':['TextPost']})
record = record.to_dict(orient="records")
results = sf.bulk.feeditem.insert(record)
results
```

What I have tried so far:

- {salesforce_id}
- {%salesforce_id}
- @FirstName LastName

Following chatter [API documentation][1] I should use messageSegments in order to mention someone, but all of my approaches fail.

Example code with messageSegments:

```
record = pd.DataFrame({'ParentId': 'parent_salesforce_id'
                      ,'Body': [[{'messageSegments': {'text' : 'Test'}}]]
                      ,'Type': 'TextPost'})
record = record.to_dict(orient="records")
results = sf.bulk.feeditem.insert(record)
results

Error message:
Out[14]: [{'success': False,
  'created': False,
  'id': None,
  'errors': [{'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD',
    'message': 'Unexpected JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize instance of textarea from START_ARRAY value [ or request may be missing a required field\n at [Source: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream@74f8b7a1; line: 1, column: 35]',
    'fields': []}]},
 {'success': False,
  'created': False,
  'id': None,
  'errors': [{'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD',
    'message': "Unexpected JsonMappingException: No such column 'messageSegments' on sobject of type FeedItem",
    'fields': []}]},
 {'success': False,
  'created': False,
  'id': None,
  'errors': [{'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD',
    'message': "Json Deserialization failed on token 'text' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row",
    'fields': ['text']}]}]
```

I have been using the same approach as previous [stack post][2] about it.
Is there anyone who might help me with this? Thank you in advance.

```
  [1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_item.htm
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165029/mentioning-chatter-request-sfdc-using-simple-salesforce-in-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a Flow but it should also work in Apex code. Try with brackets:

```
'@['+salesforce_id+']'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @q-jack I am afraid it still renders as a text in salesforce my code: salesforce_id = '12345'
record = pd.DataFrame({'ParentId':['54321'],
                       'Body':['@['+salesforce_id+']' + 'Another Test.'],
                       'Type':['TextPost']})
record = record.to_dict(orient="records")
results = sf.bulk.feeditem.insert(record)
results

Comment: '12345' is not valid userId. User should exist and should be active

Comment: Yeah. Just replaced valid salesforceid with a dummy one for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It renders as Text.
What you can do is creating a Flow with the Chatter Action and call the the flow in your apex class, but maybe someone has a solution for the apex code